# Find a string in a list of strings and replace it with a corresponding value - Python

Tags: python, list, search

I have a list of strings - List A

```
['red fruit', 'orange', 'banana', 'fruit with potassium']
```

I want to find each of the strings in list A in a list of lists (List B):

```
[['apple', 'red fruit'], ['banana', 'fruit with potassium'], ['orange', 'citrus fruit']]
```

and replace it with a corresponding value (from List C) for the identified list in List B

List C - `['apple', 'banana', 'orange']`

The final replaced list (answer) for List A should be:

```
['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'banana']
```

It would also be better if List B and List C are stored in a better data structure.

I am unable to find a way to write this programmatically.

Comment: "It would also be better if List B and List C are stored in a better data structure." Have you seen dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use List Comprehension, and iterate the lists and check for the conditions i.e. common between first and second list and second and third list:

```py
>>> [c for a in list_a for b in list_b for c in list_c if a in b and c in b]
['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'banana']
```

**PS:** The sole purpose of list-comprehension is to make the code clean, and more readable. However, for this type of nested iterations, I'd actually prefer to iterate the values in traditional loop to make the code more readable.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could share if there is a more optimal way of doing this. Anything better than O(n^3), perhaps something like combining List B and List C into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
a = ['red fruit', 'orange', 'banana', 'fruit with potassium']

b = [['apple', 'red fruit'], ['banana', 'fruit with potassium'], ['orange', 'citrus fruit']]

c = a[:]
for item in b:
    for j,k in enumerate(a):
        if item[1] == k:
            a[j] = item[0]
a,c = c,a
print(a)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make list B into a `dict` that maps from the word-to-be-replaced to its replacement:

```py
list_a = ['red fruit', 'orange', 'banana', 'fruit with potassium']
list_b = [['apple', 'red fruit'], ['banana', 'fruit with potassium'], ['orange', 'citrus fruit']]

# Build dict/map out of list_b
replacement_map = {}
for (value, key) in list_b:
    replacement_map[key] = value

# Build list_c
list_c = []
for item in list_a:
    if item in replacement_map:
        list_c.append(replacement_map[item])
    else:
        list_c.append(item)
```

Comment: I like your idea of making a map out of list b for efficiency. But, list C need not have the same values as in list b. Hence, you might want to make use of list c.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the problem statement. However, yes - there are a lot of ways you can use `list_c` as a "filter". For example, when constructing the output list, use `if item in replacement_map and replacement_map[item] in list_c:`.

Comment: Simply put, Parent categories (list_c) contains many sub-category words (list_b). I have a few sub-category words (list_a) which I need to find the bucket it belongs (list_b) and replace it with the corresponding parent category (list_c).

Answer (score 0):

Try this with dicts for **1 vs 1 situation**:

```
list_ini = ['red fruit', 'orange', 'banana', 'fruit with potassium']
list_match = [['apple', 'red fruit'], ['banana', 'fruit with potassium'], ['orange', 'citrus fruit']]
list_fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']

dict_fruits = {}
for i in list_match:
    dict_fruits[i[1]] = i[0]
# print(dict_fruits)
list_rep = [dict_fruits[x] if x in dict_fruits else x for x in list_ini]
print(list_rep)
```

Try this with dicts for **N vs 1 situation** if I understand the comment correctly:

```
list_ini = ['red fruit', 'orange', 'banana', 'fruit with potassium', 'yellow fruit', 'citrus fruit', 'orange fruit', 'VitaminC']
list_match = [['apple', 'red fruit'], ['banana', 'fruit with potassium', 'yellow fruit'], ['orange', 'citrus fruit', 'orange fruit', 'VitaminC']]
list_fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']

list_new = []
for x, char in enumerate(list_ini):
    for i in range(len(list_match)):
        for j in range(len(list_match[i])):
            if list_match[i][j] == char:
                print(f'{char} is a description of {list_match[i][0]}')
                # print(f"Index of 'char': {i}")
                # print(list_match[i][0])
                fruit_rep = list_match[i][0]
                list_new.append(fruit_rep)
print(list_new)
```

Comment: I understand your approach. But you may want to make use of `list_fruits` for the replacement as `list_fruits` can contain different values. i.e, `list_fruits` is the parent and `list_match` contains all possible child for the corresponding parent in `list_fruits` (VitaminC -> orange, citrus fruit..)

Comment: I edited the code for the N vs 1 situation, and make sure the parent is always in the first element in the lists of the list_match list.